# Will rebase include the old feature branch in a PR?

Tags: git

There is a feature branch I submitted a PR for, and it hasn't been approved yet. Now there is a new feature I have to work on that should be based on that feature branch. I thought of using re-base to start working on the new branch with the latest commits from the other feature branch (that hasn't been approved/merged yet). In this case, when I submit a PR for the new feature branch, will that PR include the commits of the old feature branch, or only the commits of the new feature branch?

Comment: Short answer, yes. A PR from branchA to master will highlight all commits from branchA up to the commit where master and branchA have started to diverge from.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer, in my case the older PR I first submitted (let's call it A), was diverged from master, then the second branch (call it B) is diverged from A. Then if I do a rebase to B and it includes A, when I submit a PR for B, will it include the commits of A? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Let's try to simplify, you have your master branch with commit M, at this point you started a branch A with commit A (which was never merged but PR was submitted). You then created a branch B along with branch A, you created a commit B. You should have the following commit sequence `M -> A -> B`. If you open a PR to request a merge from branch B to master, you branch B has 2 commits the master branch doesn't have (A and B) so these two will be seen in the PR.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin and this makes perfect sense, so I don't understand how a rebase is different here - if I have this branch A and I branch out from A to B, and then create a new commit in B branch - how is it different from creating branch B from master, doing rebase to include branch A and then creating a new commit? If I understand correctly, it would only be different if the master branch got additional commits right? Otherwise both options are exactly the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git itself is totally ignorant of pull requests (which are a GitHub or Bitbucket feature if you're using GitHub or Bitbucket: note that GitLab has something similar, but they are called MRs, Merge Requests).  So `git rebase` doesn't *know* that some commit(s) are in some PR(s); it literally cannot know this.

Answering this question correctly therefore requires defining both the PR process *and* the rebase operation.  Since you haven't specified the hosting site, defining the PR part is not possible, but we can generalize a bit:

- To make a pull request or merge request on some hosting site, we must `git push` some set of commits *to* that site, then use the features of that site to generate the PR/MR.  The PR/MR goes into some non-Git auxiliary database where people can inspect it and fuss with it and do whatever, but in any case, there is some set of commits involved, and *initially*, at least, those commits include the ones you sent with `git push`.
- `git rebase` is all about *copying* commits: we have some existing set of commits, where we like some thing(s) about those commits, but we dislike some other thing(s) about those commits.  No *commit* can ever be changed: the actual name of a commit is its hash ID, and its hash ID is determined by doing a hashing operation on its content (specifically on the metadata but the metadata depend on the data as well, so we get a Merkle-tree-ish setup, where the final hash covers everything).

When we copy the commits using `git rebase`, we then instruct our Git to *stop using* the old commits in favor of the new, copied commits.  *This has no effect on copies that are in other Git repositories*, because it literally can't: those copies are *their* copies, and like all commits, cannot be changed.  We *may* be able to instruct those other Git repositories to stop using the original commits and start using others instead.  If, when, and how that influences any Pull Requests is up to those other sites.

When we use `git rebase`, we must tell our own Git software two things:

- Which commits should it copy?  Which ones *shouldn't* it copy?  (This is one thing, with two sides, like the two sides of one coin.)
- Where should the copies go?

Git *finds* commits through branch names, and for `git rebase`, the end result *of* the rebase is reflected by taking one branch name—just one, at least for now—and making it *find* the new copies instead of the originals that we copied.

So, we have some branch names that find some commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Here, we are "on" branch `feature2` in our Git repository.  The name `feature2` finds commit `L` specifically: that commit is the *tip commit* of the current branch.  Commit `L` finds commit `K`, which finds commit `J`, which finds commit `I`, which finds commit `H`, and so on, backwards, in Git's usual fashion.

Meanwhile, branch name `feature1` finds commit `J`: commit `J` is the *tip* commit of branch `feature1`.  The name `main` finds `H`, so `H` is the tip commit of branch `main`.  *All the commits* are on branch `feature2`, even though commits up through and including `H` are on `main`, and commits up through and including `J` are on `feature1`.

Git has two ways to use a branch name (or anything that finds any one specific commit): it can either select *just that one commit*, or it can *select that one commit with history*.  The "select with history" operation is kind of like a [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), except that it only goes one direction, namely backwards.  For ordinary commits that have just one parent, it's straightforward; for merge commits, that have two or more parents, that's when we need something more complex.

In any case, the general form of rebase is:<sup>1</sup>

```
git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>
```

The *`upstream`* argument is the "what not to copy" specifier.  Git selects this with history, "flood filling" the commit graph with temporary "red paint".  The commits thus painted *won't* get copied.

The commits that *do* get copied are then selected via `HEAD`, i.e., the current branch name.<sup>2</sup>  Git selects this with history, "flood filling" the commit graph with temporary "green paint", but *not overwriting any red*.  So only the commits *not specifically de-selected* get copied.

The copies then go *after* the commit specified by the *`target`* argument.

If you omit the `--onto` and *`target`* argument, the target for the rebase is the commit specified by the *`upstream`* argument.  This works well for cases like:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

where we just run `git rebase mainline`.  Git paints all the `o` and `*` commits red (temporarily), then paints `C-B-A` green and stops because `*` is red, and thus copies `C-B-A`.

Having chosen commits to copy, Git makes sure to put them into the correct order.  Git also *knocks out* specific commits:

- If `--fork-point` is active, commits via the fork-point selection are dropped.
- Unless `--preserve-merges` (now deprecated) or `--rebase-merges` are in effect, all *merge* commits are dropped.
- "Patch-ID-equivalent" commits are dropped (Git uses the symmetric difference code for this, so it's really using `upstream...HEAD` rather than `upstream..HEAD` as claimed in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)).

The remaining commits form the list to be copied (or, for interactive rebase, turned into `pick` commands, before those are perhaps modified by `--autosquash`).

Having generated the correct list, Git then uses `git switch --detach target` to get to the commit where the copies go.  It then uses `git cherry-pick` or equivalent<sup>3</sup> to copy each commit.

(There is, however, a short-cut that rebase will sometimes use here: if the commit to be copied *is* the next commit, Git will *fast-forward* over that commit.  You can suppress this with `git rebase --force` or similar options: see the documentation.)

Once all the commits are copied (or fast-forwarded into place if allowed and possible), Git will take the original branch name, whatever it was, and force it to point to the last-copied commit.  For our mainline-and-feature example just above, the result is this:

```
                   A'-B'-C'  <-- feature (HEAD)
                  /
...--o--*--o--o--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

The temporary red-and-green-paint stuff is automatically deleted: in fact, it never got into the repository at all, as it's just in memory while Git is running the symmetric difference operation to generate the list of commits to copy.  (It's not even "paint", it's just some bits in some data structures.  The paint idea is to help visualize the effect.)

---

<sup>1</sup>You can add one more parameter, `<branch>`, but that just means *run `git switch` to that branch first, then go back to the general form.  When the rebase is done, you're "on" the given branch, as if you had run `git switch` yourself.  So I prefer to discount this case.

<sup>2</sup>If you run `git rebase` while in detached HEAD mode, Git still selects the commits the same way.  It just omits the "move one branch name" step at the end.

<sup>3</sup>Older Git versions use `git format-patch` and `git am` by default here; you have to force them to use the cherry-pick mode, except for interactive rebase, which requires actual cherry-picking.

---

#### Interactions with Pull Requests

Suppose we start with:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

and `git push` both `feature1` (commits `I-J`) and `feature2` (`K-L`) to a GitHub repository, then use the GitHub CLI or web interface to make two PRs.  The `feature1` PR will ask someone to add commits `I-J` to some branch of some GitHub fork.  The `feature2` PR will ask someone to add commits `I-J-K-L` to some branch of some GitHub fork.

**Whether or not anyone has done any of this** we now run `git switch feature2 && git rebase --onto main feature1`, using the `--onto` operation to produce:

```
          K'-L'  <-- feature2 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   [abandoned]
```

*No change has occurred in any repository on GitHub yet.*

If we now `git push` the updated `feature2` to *our* GitHub fork *from which we generated* the `feature2` PR, *GitHub* will—after requiring us to use `--force` with this `git push` operation—update both our fork *and* our PR.  Our new PR will have commits `K'-L'` in it.  **If someone has already merged the old commits or otherwise used them in any way, we're too late.**  They have our `K-L` commits.  If not, they can still get to our `K-L` commits, but the easy operations they have easy access to will use our `K'-L'` commits.

If we *don't* use `--onto`, and copy commits `I-J-K-L` with `--force` or in any other way such that we get:

```
          I'-J'-K'-L'  <-- feature2 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   [abandoned]
```

and `git push --force` this to our GitHub fork to update or `feature2` PR, we've now included the *new copies*, `I'-J'`, as part of that PR.  Should someone *literally* merge *both* our PRs, *both copies* of these commits will wind up in their merge result.  But GitHub have "accept this PR" buttons that don't actually *use* `git merge`, but rather do the equivalent of either `git rebase --force` or `git merge --squash`.  In those cases, *none of our commits* (by hash ID) wind up in their merge result.  Our *code* may or may not wind up in their merge result.

#### Conclusion

The bottom line, as it were, is that you *must know what rebase does* and look at it terms of which commits go where in the commit graph.  But this only tells you about *your* repository.  When you `git push` to your GitHub fork, this adds any new commits you have and adjusts the branch names *in your fork* to point to the new commits as requested or commanded by your `git push` (without force = polite request, with `--force` or `--force-with-lease` or similar = command).

*On GitHub*, pushing to a branch that has an open PR causes the other guy, whoever that is, to see the new commits as part of the PR.  The old ones are still accessible, but much harder to find than the new ones.  On other systems, you get whatever they give you.

**Always draw the graph** (in your head if nowhere else).

Comment: Thank you so much torek for your great and well detailed explanation, I couldn't have asked for a more thorough answer! I would just like to ask please, if we take your last example, when we use rebase without --onto, so that feature2 now has the copied commits I and J from feature1, if we compare this scenario with the one where we don't use rebase - so we just have feature1 with I and J, and then feature2 with K and L (not abandoned now) - how is this scenario different than the one with rebase (without --onto) in terms of submitting PR for feature2? Wouldn't the PR look identical? Thanks!

Comment: GitHub don't show the commit *graph*, so they would in fact look identical *on GItHub* (as long as you don't dig into the commit hash IDs). However, if you fetch (as in `git fetch`) the specific commits using the `refs/pull/` namespace names, you'll see the copied commits, when there are copied commits, and that there are no copied commits when there are no copied commits (provided, of course, that you look carefully in your own repository after fetching).

Comment: I see now that makes perfect sense thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume for master commits are m1-m2.

Your feature A branch rebased on master as m1-m2-**a1**.

PR for branch A has one commit. **a1**

if you rebase feature B on feature A, your tree is m1-m2-a1-**b1**

PR for branch B will have 2 commits **a1,b1**

once your PR1 is complete with rebase your master will be **m1-m2-a1**.  your PR for branch b will eventually have only 1 commit **b1**.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm trying to understand your answer, so if I get it right, if my PR includes previous commits from rebase and then those commits were merged in another PR, then my current PR won't include those anymore and they would just disappear?

Comment: your PR request for 2 branches is actually the head commit of each branch. once feature 1 is merged with master it will already have that commit. if you squash the commits while merging, the above wont be true as your master branch will be m1-m2-s1 and your pr for feature 2 will become a1-b2.